# Asp.net how to correct the error

Tags: asp.net

im designing my web page, in that i have typed in the book id and typed
Nameofthebook.  and then click the button the  stack of book are available is go to another page and then not available is display the error message is book is not available My project (Library management system)

```
     using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

 public partial class Bookcheck : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = null;
        constr = 





 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["librarymanagementconnetionstring"].ConnectionStrin

    g

  ;
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(constr);
        cnn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT*FROM BOOKREGISTRATIONDETAILS WHERE   
     bookId='" + txtid.Text.Trim() + "'AND Nameofbook='" + txtnb.Text.Trim() + "'", 
     constr);
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Issueofbook.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Msg.Text = "NO book available";
            Msg.Visible = true;
        }
    }
     }

 }




              My error
           NULL reference exception in un handle by the user

               constr =  




 ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["librarymanagementconnetionstring"].ConnectionStrin
 g;
```

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code into a readable state. Tip: in Visual Studio, select the code that you want to include, press <SHIFT>+<TAB> until the outermost scope has no indentation, copy, paste into the editor here, select the code and then press <CTRL>+<K>. That will look a lot neater.

Comment: When formatting the message, make sure you wrote whole code, then selected the whole code and then clicked the toolbar button for marking that as a code snippet. For now your post is unreadable, at least for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the config file that you use has a connection string defined with the name `librarymanagementconnetionstring`. I think it does not have that, which makes `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["librarymanagementconnetionstring"]` return `null`, causing a `NullReferenceException` when you try to access the `ConnectionString` property.

It should look something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add 
        name="librarymanagementconnetionstring" 
        connectionString="[connection string goes here]"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring with an incorrect connection string key `librarymanagementconnetionstring`.